# Embarrassingly parallel hyperparameter search via Azure + DataBricks + MLFlow

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, mlflow

Conceptual question.  My company is pushing Azure + DataBricks.  I am trying to understand where this can take us.

I am porting some work I've done locally to the Azure + Databricks platform.  I want to run an experiment with a large number of hyperparameter combinations using Azure + Databricks + MLfLow.  I am using PyTorch to implement my models.

I have a cluster with 8 nodes.  I want to kick off the parameter search across all of the nodes in an embarrassingly parallel manner (one run per node, running independently).  Is this as simple as creating a MLflow project and then using the mlflow.projects.run command for each hyperparameter combination and Databricks + MLflow will take care of the rest?

Is this technology capable of this?  I'm looking for some references I could use to make this happen.

Comment: I ended up switching to the Azure machine learning Python SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, it's possible, but won't be exactly as easy as running a single mlflow command. You can paralelize single-node workflows using spark Python UDFs, a good example of this is this [notebook](https://pages.databricks.com/rs/094-YMS-629/images/Fine-Grained-Time-Series-Forecasting.html?_ga=2.64430959.1760852900.1593769579-972789996.1561118598)

I'm not sure if this will work with pytorch, but there is hyperopt library that lets you parallelize search across parameters using Spark - it's integrated with mlflow and available in databricks ML runtime. I've been using it only with scikit-learn, but it may be [worth checking out](https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/automl/hyperopt/hyperopt-model-selection.html)